# How to kill MySqlWorkBench process in Ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, mysql, kill

I have installed Mysql Workbench on My machine (ubuntu 14.04 LTS)

Lately this software is hanging alot. I want to kill the process

I ran the command

> ps aux

but I'm unable to find the Mysql Workbench process. Please suggest me how can I find the MysqlWorkbench process instead of listing all the processes.

And is there any other faster and lighter Mysql query browser for Ubuntu ?

And yes I'm new at Ubuntu

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Search for mysql-workbench in the processes.

```
$ps -ef |grep mysql-workbench
XX    8327  1159  0 12:04 ?  00:00:00 /bin/bash /usr/bin/mysql-workbench
XX    8330  8327  0 12:04 ?  00:00:00 /bin/sh /usr/bin/catchsegv /usr/lib/mysql-workbench/mysql-workbench-bin
```

2nd column will have the process ID to kill. In this case 8327. It will also stop the 2nd line.

Regarding the options: -ef options help us to list all processes (-e) using full-format syntax (-f)

> And is there any other faster and lighter Mysql query browser for Ubuntu ?

[See](http://alternativeto.net/software/mysql-workbench/?platform=linux) but I doubt they will be as good.

Comment: thanks it worked just fine. This what i need can please even explain what is "-ef" flags ?

Comment: Could you explain the next step? (Killing the MySQL Workbench process.)

Answer (score 9):

You can also use:

```
pkill mysql-workbench
```

It's hanging for me also, so if you want to kill it and restart it, use:

```
pkill mysql-workbench && mysql-workbench &
```

(the & at the end is to do the command in the background)